# Access Report showing transactions for 15, 30, 60 days on the report

Tags: ms-access, report

I am working on a comprehensive report where we are importing csv data into access and then report generation is done for 15, 30, 60 days.

I managed to get individual reports by creating queries filtering data on the basis of 15, 30, 60 days separately.

But the next required operation is to get a single report showing all 15, 30, 60 days transactions and then grand total on the basis of ID as primary key.

Can anyone please suggest any specific query or method to make things simple and easy please.

I am not too much expert so please suggest accordingly.

regards,

Comment: We need data sources, data sample, report structure, etc. etc. to help. As now this is too broad.